Deserialize custom messages on consumer
Im experimenting with Spring Cloud Stream and Kafka and banging my head on what I believe to be a simple issue: Simple message deserialization on consumer.
I have the following Spring config:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        processData-in-0:
          destination: test.public.huge_test_table
          group: my-consumer-group
          content-type: application/json
          consumer:
            concurrency: 10
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092

And I have this Kafka topic with messages which the payload is the following format (I can check these messages through Kafdrop for instance):
{
    "metadata": {
         // ...
    },
    "payload": {
        title: "Whatever"
        // ...
    },
    "op": "c"
}

I have then created my DTOs:
data class Foo<T> (
    @JsonProperty("payload")
    val payload: T
    @JsonProperty("op")
    val op: String
)

data class Bar (
    @JsonProperty("title")
    val title: String,
    //...
)

And to consume those messages I try doing:
@Configuration
class MyListener {

    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    @Bean
    fun processData(): Consumer<Message<Foo<Bar>> {
        return Consumer { message ->
            logger.info { "Received message: ${message.payload}" }
        }
    }
}

That however throws an error like
 class [B cannot be cast to class com.example.dto.FooDTO ([B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.dto.FooDTO is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Checking the message object on the consumer, I can see it is a GenericMessage type with a payload that contains a ByteArray (hence the B in the error, probably).
However if I use Consumer<Message<String>> I can see the payload as the expect JSON string.
My expectation would be that by setting Consumer<Message<Foo<Bar>>> it would use the ObjectMapper on my application context to deserialize that JSON, much like it does with Spring web...?
I also tried configuring some custom message serializers/deserializers but failed doing so.
I can of course keep the Message<String> to get the JSON payload and then manually injecting an ObjectMapper and deserialize it by myself, but I expected configuring this in a more smooth way.
Basically the following works but I dont want to have to inject ObjectMapper and manually deserialize it everytime:
    @Bean
    fun processData(): Consumer<Message<String>> {
        return Consumer { message ->
            val payload = objectMapper.readValue<Foo<Bar>>(message.payload.toString())
            logger.info { "Received message: ${message.payload}" }
        }
    }

I also tried providing a MessageConverter bean that would basically set my ObjectMapper although I think thats already default, it was some suggestion I saw
    @Bean
    fun customMessageConverter(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): MessageConverter {
        val converter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
        converter.objectMapper = objectMapper
        return converter
    }

So is it possible? What am I missing?
Thanks!
Edit
After further investigation, I realized the deserialization fails because the payload JSON has unknown fields to my DTO.
I do have the spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false (which is default anyway), but it only works if I annotate the DTO with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true). Trying to understand why is that.

I suggest checking if Debezium has a public library for their  CDC data exchange format rather than writing your own... Otherwise, you've not set up the necessary value.deserializer property in your config. Please show what you tried

Have you tried to convert your JSON to your DTO structure using simple ObjectMapper? If so how is it configured? The fact that you get CCE means that non of 5 framework-based converters were able to convert your input, so something is not right. Also, you can skip content-type: application/json as it is default.

@OneCricketeer altough Im indeed using Debezium, its not a Debezium question. I just want to deserialize the kafka event in a clean way. I can write any message on the topic with my DTO format and it will fail just like that.
@OlegZhurakousky if I have a Message<String>, inject an ObjectMapper and then use it to deserialize the message.payload it does work. However, I was expecting to not have to do that manually and simply delegate it to Spring Cloud (maybe) to do that deserialization and simply use Message<Foo<Bar>>? Will update with those examples ASAP

Edited my question, let me know if thats any clear. Thanks!

My point was that Debezium has a built-in class for the {metadata, payload, op} class. You don't need your own. You can add debezium-core as a dependency in your consumer codebase https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/main/debezium-core/src/main/java/io/debezium/serde/DebeziumSerdes.java  https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/main/debezium-core/src/main/java/io/debezium/serde/json/JsonSerde.java

I see, will check that @OneCricketeer! I have an update as well. I figured out the deserialization is not working because the JSON contains extra fields that my DTO doesnt. Although I have spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false in my config, it only work if I explicit set @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) on my DTO

After further digging in the source code, I could find the default JsonMessageConverter used by spring-cloud-function is using a JsonMapper under the hood which seems not to be considering my ObjectMapper properties.
To get around it, what I did was register a custom MappingJackson2MessageConverter that uses my applications ObjectMapper and takes care of deserializing generic types:
    @Bean
    fun customMessageConverter(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): MessageConverter {
        return object: MappingJackson2MessageConverter() {

            init {
                this.objectMapper = objectMapper
            }

            override fun convertFromInternal(message: Message<*>, targetClass: Class<*>, conversionHint: Any?): Any? {
                try {
                    val type = if (conversionHint is ParameterizedType) {
                        objectMapper.typeFactory.constructType(conversionHint)
                    } else {
                        objectMapper.constructType(targetClass)
                    }
                    return objectMapper.readValue(message.payload as ByteArray, type)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    throw MessageConversionException("couldnt convert", e)
                }
            }
        }
    }

Not sure if it is the best way but it worked
